# Sending push notification to a specific user's app on android using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

My question is how do i 'tell' the GCM notification for android to send a push notification to a specific  user's app.I've read all tutorials on how to send a push notification from my server to GCM and then GCM sends it to it to a phone but I just can't get how to select a user's app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins meant for this, which you can install using plugman or the CLI, specifically for GCM push notifications, you can use the push-plugin, instructions on installation and use can be found here:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Also, as a side note, there are good sites to find cordova/phonegap/phonegap build plugins, here are two sources to take into consideration:

- http://plugreg.com/plugins
- http://plugins.cordova.io

After you follow the installation and use instructions, you only need to use the proper code in your application to handle the notifications.

Answer (score 5):

Every application made for iOS or Android platforms has to register for push notifications individually.By registering i mean that the app will receive a unique ID from either APNS(iOS) or GCM(Android) based on which platform you are developing.This unique ID is commonly referred to as device token.This device token is unique for each app installed in a particular device.

If you want to track a particular user's device token, you can request the user to input his/her username in your application and after getting the username and device token, you have to save those data to your server using web service.

Now you can easily query a particular user to get the associated device token and send push notifications only to the user using that particular app in a device using a server side language like PHP,python,etc.

Hope my answer is clear to you.

Comment: What if multiple users share same device?

Comment: If multiple users are sharing the same device,in that case you can get the user id at the time they log in to the device by posting the data from the app.After getting the user id,you can send notifications specific to the logged in user by writing some server side logic.